# R parallel - parRapply not working properly

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rparallel

I'm doing some unit testing on a package in development. One of the tests is failing. Specifically, I have parallel versions of the code and non-parallel versions. The non-parallel version works perfectly. The parallel version fails a unit test, with a seemingly nonsensical error.

```
## load my development package.
library(devtools) # for install_github
install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation")

## do some setup:
library(imputation)
library(kernlab)
library(parallel)


x1 <- matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
x1[x1 > 1.25] <- NA
x3 <- create_canopies(x1, n_canopies= 5, q= 2)
prelim <- imputation:::impute_prelim(x3[[1]], parallel= TRUE, leave_cores= 1)

opt_h <- (4 * sd(x3[[1]][, -ncol(x3[[1]])], na.rm=T)^5 / (3 * nrow(x3[[1]])))^(1/5)
kern <- rbfdot(opt_h)


## write 2 identical functions:
## one in parallel
## one not in parallel

foo_parallel <- function(x_missing, x_complete, k, q, leave_cores) {
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - leave_cores)
  x_missing_imputed <- parRapply(cl= cl, x_missing, function(i, x_complete) {
    rowID = as.numeric(i[1])
    i_original = unlist(i[-1])
    x_comp_rowID <- which(as.integer(rownames(x_complete)) == rowID)
    missing_cols <- which(is.na(x_complete[x_comp_rowID,]))

    # calculate distances
    distances <- imputation:::dist_q.matrix(x=rbind(x_complete[x_comp_rowID, ], 
                                                    x_complete[-x_comp_rowID,]), ref= 1L,  q= q)
    return(distances)
  }, x_complete= x_complete)
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(x_missing_imputed)
}

foo_nonparallel <- function(x_missing, x_complete, k, q) {
  x_missing_imputed <- t(apply(x_missing, 1, function(i, x_complete) {
    rowID = as.numeric(i[1])
    i_original = unlist(i[-1])
    x_comp_rowID <- which(as.integer(rownames(x_complete)) == rowID)
    missing_cols <- which(is.na(x_complete[x_comp_rowID,]))

    # calculate distances
    distances <- imputation:::dist_q.matrix(x=rbind(x_complete[x_comp_rowID, ], 
                                                    x_complete[-x_comp_rowID,]), ref= 1L,  q= q)
    return(distances)
  }, x_complete= x_complete))
  return(x_missing_imputed)
}

## test them
foo_parallel(prelim$x_missing, x3[[1]],k=3,q=2, leave_cores= 1) # fails
foo_nonparallel(prelim$x_missing, x3[[1]],k=3,q=2) # works
```

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>     2 nodes produced errors; first error: ref must be an integer in {1, nrow(x)}.

As you can see, `ref` is clearly defined as `ref= 1L` which is in 1, nrow(x).

**What is going on with the interaction with `library(parallel)` that is causing this error?**

**Edit** - I'm on a windows machine:

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Comment: clearly one of [these three things](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation/blob/master/R/utilities_knn.R#L30) is true

Comment: @rawr Yes, I realize that I'm meeting my error criteria. But I don't understand why. `ref == 1` which should not be caught by the error criteria

Comment: idk.. actually both of them work for me (mac). the results look nearly identical only one returns a vector and the other returns a matrix.

Comment: Really?! I'm on a windows machine--are you on Mac/Linux?

Comment: @rawr regarding your return--yes I have to do some post processing in the parallel version since it returns a vector. But I've avoided that in this example for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out what is causing the problem. This seems to me to be a `library(parallel)` bug / edge-case, specific to the parallelized versions of the apply functions (in this case `parRapply`). Perhaps someone older and wiser can explain why there isn't a catch in `library(parallel)` for this edge case.

**The issue seems to be related to the number of tasks vs the number of workers available. On my machine, I have an 8-core processor. In this case, there are 5 tasks (one for each row of `prelim$x_missing`).**

> Granted, in typical use, I wouldn't be parallelizing work for 5 rows. This is just a unit test.

```
R> prelim$x_missing
              X1         X2         X3         X4         X5          X6         X7         X8          X9        X10 d_factor
6   6  0.2604170 -0.5966874         NA         NA -0.3013053  0.24313272  0.2836760  0.3977164 -0.60711109 -0.2929253        1
7   7 -0.8540576  0.1409047         NA  0.4801685 -0.9324517 -0.06487733 -0.2220201         NA  1.19077335 -0.3702607        2
8   8  0.5118453 -0.8750674         NA  0.1787238  0.6897163  0.20695122         NA -0.3488021  0.84200408 -0.4791230        1
12 12  0.3695746 -0.4919277 -1.2509180  1.1642152         NA  0.04018417         NA         NA -0.53436589 -1.5400345        2
15 15         NA -0.3608242 -0.6761515 -0.5366562  0.1763501          NA         NA  0.4967595  0.02635203 -0.6015536        1
```

Note that I am making the cluster via `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(detectCores() - leave_cores)` where detectCores() will return 8 for my current machine. The function call accepts a parameter for the number of cores to leave open `leave_cores`. When I make a cluster with more cores/nodes than rows in the use-case, the function fails. When I make a cluster with <= number of rows, the function works:

```
 # works : detectCores() == 8, 8 - 3 == 5 (number of rows / processes)
R> foo_parallel(prelim$x_missing, x3[[1]],k=3,q=2, leave_cores= 3)
 [1] 1.0216313 0.7355635 0.9201501 0.6906554 0.6613939 0.3628872 0.9995641 0.8571252 0.9271800 0.9201501 0.9238215 0.9798824 0.9059506
[14] 0.6891484 1.0158223 0.5442953 0.6906554 0.9238215 0.8607280 0.5897955 1.1084943 0.8518322 0.9227102 0.6613939 0.9798824 0.8607280
[27] 0.9518105 0.9792209 1.1968528 0.4447104 0.3628872 0.9059506 0.5897955 0.9518105 1.1249624

# fails : 8-2 = 6; 6 > nrow(prelim$x_missing)
R> foo_parallel(prelim$x_missing, x3[[1]],k=3,q=2, leave_cores= 2) 
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: ref must be an integer in {1, nrow(x)}.
```

#### tl,dr

As described in the [rparallel vignette](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf), `detectCores` is used to simply detect the cores, it very reasonably does not attempt to do any intelligent assignment of tasks to workers.

> function detectCores() tries to determine the number of CPU cores in the machine on which R is running: it has ways to do so on all known current R
>   platforms. What exactly it measures is OS-specific: we try where possible to report the number of physical cores available. On Windows the default is to report the number of logical CPUs. On modern hardware (e.g. Intel Core i7 ) the latter may not be unreasonable as hyper-threading does give a significant
>   extra throughput.

I am calling the function `parallel::parRapply` to do the computation. `parRapply` dispatches the work to the workers via the `splitRows` function. But there doesn't seem to be any intelligence or error-catching to the `splitRows` function.

```
R> parRapply
function (cl = NULL, x, FUN, ...) 
{
    cl <- defaultCluster(cl)
    do.call(c, clusterApply(cl = cl, x = splitRows(x, length(cl)), 
        fun = apply, MARGIN = 1L, FUN = FUN, ...), quote = TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000380ca530>
<environment: namespace:parallel>
```

I can't find the source code for `splitRows` but `parallel::splitIndices` seems similar:

```
R> parallel:::splitIndices
function (nx, ncl) 
{
    i <- seq_len(nx)
    if (ncl == 0L) 
        list()
    else if (ncl == 1L || nx == 1L) 
        list(i)
    else {
        fuzz <- min((nx - 1L)/1000, 0.4 * nx/ncl)
        breaks <- seq(1 - fuzz, nx + fuzz, length = ncl + 1L)
        structure(split(i, cut(i, breaks)), names = NULL)
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000380a7828>
<environment: namespace:parallel>
```

In my unit test, this would execute as the following:

```
# all 8 cores:
nx <- 5; ncl <- 8
i <- seq_len(nx)
fuzz <- min((nx - 1L)/1000, 0.4 * nx / ncl)
breaks <- seq(1 - fuzz, nx + fuzz, length= ncl + 1L)
structure(split(i, cut(i, breaks)), names = NULL)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
integer(0)

[[5]]
[1] 3

[[6]]
[1] 4

[[7]]
integer(0)

[[8]]
[1] 5
```

Where there are 3 integer(0)s, which cause failure further down the call stack.

```
# 3 cores (just showing the return):
structure(split(i, cut(i, breaks)), names = NULL)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 5
```

If anyone can provide a link in the comments below to the source code for `splitRows`, I'll happily update this answer. Code for `parallel::clusterApply` and `parallel:::staticClusterApply` are easily found